# How to make an admin panel in android

Tags: android, datetime, passwords, admin, android-alertdialog

I am currently developing an app for a company for employee attendance.

Employees scan their QR code via android camera (using ZXing Library) and i m getting the phone's current time and date and storing it into a database.

My question is that

- I want to restrict the normal employees so that they can't change the time or date of phone.
- But there should be an option for a particalur administrator to change the time/date.
- Or I want to set a password. when any body wants to change the time/date of phone, it should pop up an alert dialog to insert the password. If password is correct then user is able to change the time/date otherwise not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely possible, given that [SureLock](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/surelockandroid.html) does it. However, they're not telling. Good luck, that's a substantial undertaking.

Comment: thanks for this.. its good idea. but can we do this via coding?

Comment: Yes, I imagine there's a way if there's a product out there that does it. Is it commonly known? Apparently not. I personally have no clue.

Comment: Same need. Would be interested to know how they do. Any clue?